How to solve "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" Error?
I am trying to copy my Java .jar file into the VM using gcloud compute scp "\Users\jinxjinx\OneDrive\Documents\lib-backend.jar" jinxjinx@12.123.123.123:/home/jinxjinx
However it is giving me an error:
gcloud compute scp "\Users\jinxjinx\OneDrive\Documents\lib-backend.jar" jinxjinx@34.124.131.199:/home/jinxjinx
Did you mean zone [asia-southeast1-b] for instance: [12.123.123.123] (Y/n)?  Y

Error fetching possible zones for instance: [12.123.123.123].
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

When I run gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-project-id
it all seems to be ok:
`bindings:

members:

serviceAccount:service-809380560661@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
role: roles/compute.serviceAgent


members:

serviceAccount:809380560661@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
serviceAccount:809380560661-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
role: roles/editor


members:

user:jinxjinx@gmail.com
role: roles/owner
etag: BwYWTQvJGOU=
version: 1`



I have also ensured that I have activated my account.
I have also ensured that my Cloud API has access to all Cloud APIs.
Thanks in advance.

I think you're making life more difficult for yourself; use:

Optional: Your gcloud SDK (Google) username
The Google Compute Engine instance's name rather than an IP

See the documentation for gcloud compute scp
I don't know how Windows (Powershell|CMD) handles line breaks so the following command should be on a single line (I've put it on multiple lines for clarity)
gcloud compute scp
  "\Users\jinxjinx\OneDrive\Documents\lib-backend.jar" 
  {INSTANCE}:/home/jinxjinx
  --zone={ZONE}
  --project={PROJECT}

Replace:

{INSTANCE} with the instance name (see below)
{ZONE} with the instance's zone
{PROJECT} with the instance's project

You should be able to describe the instance with the following command:
gcloud compute instance describe {INSTANCE} --zone={ZONE} --project=${PROJECT}

In the gcloud compute scp command, I've omitted your gcloud user account. In your example, you used pcssteffi which may not be correct. You can determine your gcloud user account using:
gcloud config get account

I think your user account is jinxjinx@gmail.com
If this is true, you may be able to omit|replace the destination folder (I'm unsure what works) because jinxjinx@gmail.com will default to the home directory (/home/jinxjinx).
